# Use a 3rd party iOS framework with Appcelerator?

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-modules

Started experimenting with `Appcelerator` platform lately and I would like to know if there is any chance of integrating one of my own framework library I wrote for the `iOS` platform in `Objective-C`, I would interested to do the similar for the `Android` platform.

I know there is the feasibility of using `JavaScript` code to communicate with native code, but is there a way to do this with the `Appcelerator` platform and my frameworks?

Thank you.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is done all the time, we call them *modules* in the Titanium sphere. In fact there is a large repository of open source modules that Appcelerator has made available, [you can find them on github here.](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules) They range from paypal integration, to bump, flurry, and drawing libraries.

Also something very helpful is the [mod dev guide](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/moddevguide) on githhub which provides code samples of common actions, [and this guide on the docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Extending_Titanium_Mobile) which pretty much outlines the whole process.

Ive made a few custom modules for iOS and its generally pretty simple, just moving code around and exposing an API or view.